# RSA encryption: negative d solution seems too big to be usable

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa

I've implemented a mostly-functional RSA encryption. It randomly generates 2048 bit primes **p** and **q** (**n = pq**) and most of the time I get a relatively small value **d** as expected. The value d is used in the encryption **M^d mod n.**

However, sometimes the value for **d** I get is negative, which is usually frowned upon in RSA. After some research, I found that a common solution is to simply add **phi** (phi = (p-1)(q-1)) in this case.

```
d = d % phi;
if(d < 0)
    d += phi;
```

But when I do this, I end up with **d** that's as large as **n** (over 2048 bits). That seems far too large to be useful. Is there something I'm missing, or is a value for **d** that large actually acceptable?

Comment: Well that does seem to be the point of adding phi. (Are phi and n the same thing?)

Comment: Yeah, logically it makes perfect sense, but in practice raising something to a 1024 bit power seems absurd. Phi = (p-1)(q-1)

Comment: How doesn't it work, then?

Comment: Like I said, I'm concerned that having d so large makes it too unwieldy to use for encryption, so I was wondering if this sort of thing is actually normal.

Comment: Why is it unwieldy? I'm going to assume the math works fine since I don't know the details of RSA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> encryption M^d mod n.

You're either using nonstandard notations that will confuse people (and probably yourself as well), or confused about how RSA works. Encryption uses the *public exponent* which is conventionally written ***e***. Decryption uses the *private exponent* which is conventionally written ***d***. Once does not use *d* to encrypt. Anybody can encrypt; decryption is what requires the private secret.

> I get a relatively small value d as expected

No, getting a small value of *d* is not expected. The public exponent *e* is usually chosen to be a constant; in principle any odd number between 2 and *n*-1 will do, but you can pick a small one with few bits set to 1 for performance (3 and 65537 are the most popular values). The private exponent *d* is calculated from the primes and it is not expected to be small. It should be almost as large as *n*. If *d* was too small then the system would be insecure (it's obviously insecure if *d* is so small that it can be guessed, and there are subtler mathematical vulnerabilities even beyond that).

> in practice raising something to a 1024 bit power seems absurd.

No, that's the way RSA works. (Except that 1024 bits is too small nowadays, 2048 is the minimum for good security.)

> sometimes the value for d I get is negative

The exponents *d* and *e* are values modulo *phi*(*n*), meaning that you can add or subtract a multiple of *phi*(*n*) and it won't change the calculations. However, it's very unusual to use a negative value; normally all the computations stay in the range [0,*n*-1]. If you're getting a negative value, you're doing something unusual somewhere.

Comment: "If you're getting a negative value, you're doing something unusual somewhere". Well, sort of. If you use the extended euclidean algorithm without modification to find the inverse of e mod phi you can get a negative number. That's why algorithms specifically for [computing the inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Computing_multiplicative_inverses_in_modular_structures) account for this.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer the technical part of your question, but came to the same issue, and if
we have

```
ed = 1 (modulo phi)
```

than the difference is multiple of *phi*:

```
ed - 1 = Q*phi
```

so we can add *e*phi* on both sides:

```
e(d + phi) - 1 = (Q + e)*phi
```

and

```
e(d + phi) = 1 (modulo phi)
```

Thus when *d* is negative, we can add *phi* and make it positive.